# compare date from database with value i get from inputtext in java jsp and sql

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, date, datetime

I have a  table , there are 4 fields:  `name`, `start date and time` (Timestamp) ,`end date and time` (timpestamp) , `car`.

In Java/MySQL,

I need to compare database start date time  and end start date time and compare with value given in textbox date time field .

*Now problem is that we need to book person(driver) and car, if car and person 
are not booked in given time (that is checked by database) , then we can booked it else not.*

Please tell me a logic/query to do this.
If you have code please mention it.

Comment: What do you mean by compare Start Date and End date in the database and compare the text box value ? .. Are you looking for the duration in the database in time ?

Comment: Are you asking the code? Try yourself and post the code if you have any doubt. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26839879/3496666) to change date format.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query,

```
SELECT name FROM table having '2014-11-28' between start_date and end_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to check availability.
`SELECT name FROM table WHERE start_date < '2014-03-13 11:42:28' AND end_date > '2014-03-13 11:42:28' limit 1`

If you get any name, then you can not book new driver. Also look at [mysql date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html).